# XML Request Using CURL

Tags: php, xml, api, rest, curl

I am using curl library to get the XML but getting error of connection with host. Following is my code, I have just removed the credentials.

```
$url="https://interface.callport.net:8080/P-RVWR-drcm01-cti/call/2142100570";

$curl_post_data = array(
  "query_type" => 'caller_info',
  "dnis" => '8883874944',
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, base64_encode('webapi@fastfix:color43t'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch))
{
  echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{    
  echo $result;
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's SSL so this usually fixes the problem. cURL does not verify the certificate then.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

[edit] I solved the problems. First the SSL as described above, then I removed the base64 encoding of the username and password, changed so the data is sent by GET instead of POST and lastly fixed the headers.

```
$url="https://interface.callport.net:8080/P-RVWR-drcm01-cti/call/2142100570?query_type=caller_info&dnis=8883874944";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'webapi@fastfix:color43t');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: Tried by adding above variable but no success.

Comment: Now I added some more to the answer. It seems to work here atleast.

Comment: Dear Karl, Appreciate your effort but not sure why I am getting the same error Curl error: couldn't connect to host. I have sent request from two of my servers but seems like I have to white list my links from intelemedia.